# Can I define variables in CQL?

Tags: cql, datastax

sample:

```
create table test1(test1Code timeuuid, primary key(test1Code));
create table test2(test2Code timeuuid, primary key(test2Code));

insert into test1(test1Code) values (now());
insert into test2(test2Code) values (now());
```

The two tables have different values for their timeuuid.

I would like to have both tables inserted with the same value of now();

Can I store the value in a variable and use that in my statement?

Or do I need to use a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

#### Perform Business Logic at the App Layer

There is no way to define / store a variable in CQL. This step should be taken care of at the app layer before you write to Cassandra using one of the datastax [drivers](http://www.datastax.com/download#dl-datastax-drivers).

#### Are you just testing?

If you're looking for a **quick and dirty** way to do this you could generate the cql commands in bash into a file and run:

```
cqlsh -f <path to file>.cql
```